# How to disable Nuxt.js automatic file based route generation in favor of a manually generated routes.js file?

Tags: vue.js, router, nuxt.js

As we may know, **Nuxt.js** generates its routes by default based on the file structure of the **pages** folder.

What I want to know is, how to use a file and put my routes by myself, manually, instead of have Nuxt.js generating them for me?

Why?

I want more control of my routes, more explicit code and less files on the project.

I think its more easy to setup route params defining them explicit into a **routes.js** file rather then setting them by adding files into the project.

Any idea of how to do that, like on a normal Vue App? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use @nuxtjs/router for that https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/router

Another option is to enchance automatic routing with https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module